# Function that takes a number and returns another number and vice versa

Tags: javascript

I recently came across a question in an interview and am stumped at how to solve it. I would really appreciate any assistance.

The question asked me to create a function that received a number as a parameter (599) and returns a different number, but will also work in reverse. The issue is that I was not permitted to use any sort of conditional operator e.g. `if`, `switch` etc...

This was as far as I got:

```
function changeValue(v) {
  // return 599 if 395 passed and vice versa
}
```

Comment: So you do not know how to do it without a condition, yet you comment on the solution below that you thought of that way??

Comment: `const x = v => v ^ 988;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about this:

```
function changeValue(v) {
    return (599 + 395) - v;
}
```

from a programming perspective, this isn't as good a solution as the one that uses an object, because an object (map/dictionary) is easier to extend to other values.

Comment: but it will return a negative number.

Comment: No it won't @ths

Comment: @chrispbacon yes it won't.

Answer (score 6):

Use an object

```js
function changeValue(v) {
  const obj = {'395': 599, '599': 395};
  return obj[v];
}

console.log(changeValue(395));
console.log(changeValue(599));
```

Comment: That's what i thought of, but is there any other way?

Comment: a clever way, edited to add an execution example though.

Comment: sure, there are other ways, what are you looking for?  (what's wrong with this one?)

Comment: Nothing wrong, but wondering is there any relation in both values,i mean can this be done by adding or subtracting something.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the explicit memoization of the argument-result-pairs in an object (see other answer) you may use a linear function (remember it from math classes) `f` of the form `f(x)=mx+b` satisfying `f(599)=395` and `f(395)=599`.
Solving this gives: `m = -1, b = 994`

```js
function changeValue(v) {
  return 994 - v;
}

console.log(changeValue(395));
console.log(changeValue(599));
```

Comment: same as my answer, but upvoting because i like your explanation.

Comment: @jdigital's answer even has a nicer representation of that solution; (395 + 599) - v just leaves 599 there if v=395 and it leaves 395 if v=599.